# Rails; Where to put this helper method for service layer / Webhook handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling with where to put this helper method.

```
  def unix_time_to_utc(sec)
    Time.at(sec).utc
  end
```

This is basically convert unix time to UTC timestamp.

I use this method in `service`/ `Webhook handler`.

It's because API returns in unix time but I'd love to convert it to UTC timestamp to save/update it to AR.

Where should I place this kind of helper method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of this question is too broad.

In my opinion, since this is a common utility method, it can be put under `/lib`. Make a new Ruby class e.g. `utils.rb`, and define the method as class method (`self.unix_time_to_utc(sec)`).

**Bonus:**

`/lib` folder can be autoloaded in `application.rb`. So this method will be available in all of your classes as `Utils.unix_time_to_utc`.